# Electron: Send message from React to Main

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, ipc

I am trying to send information from my react code (through ipcRenderer) to my `index.electron.js` file (listening on ipcMain), but the message is not being picked up.

The exact flow is:

1. Send message from `mainWindow.webContents`
2. Execute some react code
3. Send message from react code back to electron
4. Electron listens to the message and executes a zoomFactor change

My code is as follows:

`index.electron.js`:

```
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

...

click: () => mainWindow.webContents.send('TEST-1', 'message sent from mainWindow') // this works

...

ipcMain.on('TEST-2', (event, arg) => { // this does not work
    console.log('IPC MAIN', arg);
});
```

`some-react-component.js`

```
ipcRenderer.on('TEST-1', (event, message) => { // this works
    console.log('react-component', message);
    ipcRenderer.send('TEST-2', 'message sent from react');
});
ipcRenderer.on('TEST-2', (event, message) => { // this works (this is just to check if TEST-2 is sending
    console.log('react-component', message);
});
```

The ipcRenderer is picking up the message sent on channels `TEST-1` and `TEST-2`, but I cannot get the `ipcMain` to listen on `TEST-2`

Thanks :)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. Just out of curiosity if you call the ipcRenderer.send outside of the on callback does it work?

Comment: Likewise, I think the problem doesn't seem to be with the code snippets that you linked. Here's a [toy example](https://gist.github.com/8a4c619966310cdb6f9345c716626d29) openable with [Electron Fiddle](https://electronjs.org/fiddle) that uses the same IPC calls to increase the zoom factor every time `mainWindow` is moved. I'm not sure if something in the rest of your code is causing this to fail or not.

Comment: Hey @Erick, thank you for confirming the code is valid. I am really stumped as to what could be the problem, but at least I know to look in other spots and that the code will work when I fix whatever is preventing it from running.

Comment: @PaulRyan Moving the code outside of the on callback didn't solve it unfortunately